# Access value of viewModel property with knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a three different Car Fuel type pages which they render a Partial View to load common functionality across all three.  I am using knockout js to perform some dynamic calculation in that partial view.

So each of my Fuel type pages has a  `BeginForm` and the id is different for each so DieselForm, PetrolForm, ElectricForm.  The fuel type is set in my viewModel and is stored in the common partial view in a hidden field -  `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FuelType)`

The following is some of my knockout js which is in the Partial View:

```
    var mvcModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(mvcModel);


    var calculateTotal = function() {

        var form = $('#DieselContent form');
        if (!form.valid()) return;

        var formData = form.serialize();

      //ajax post to server method removed for brevity
```

Is there a way I can pull the FuelType value from the viewModel property and then dynamically change the form var based on which FuelType is set - i.e - it should be either `var form = $('#DieselContent form');` or `var form = $('#PetrolContent form');` or `var form = $('#ElectricContent form');`

I tried using var fuelType = viewModel.FuelType.val();  but that throws an undefined error.

Comment: Does the FuelType change during the user's interaction with the form? If not you could just use the property mvcModel.FuelType without looking in the ko veiwmodel.

Comment: @PollyShaw No it does not change with User Interaction - I will give that a try - how about the second part - dynamically building the var form based on that value?

Comment: that sounds like it would work.

Comment: @PollyShaw - I mean more what is the correct way to build up that differing #id for the form variable if that makes sense.  If you can put this in answer I can mark accepted

Comment: I guess I could possibly just concatenate the string to form the one I need.

Comment: Does the `viewModel` variable available to the `calculateTotal` function at all?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to achieve the result you want, so the one you choose comes down to architectural decisions. If you were strictly referencing only the ViewModel then you could select the form using

```
 var form = $('#' + viewModel.FuelType() + 'Content form');
```

However, in this case CalculateTotal references a form (part of the presentation) so it doesn't really seem to be strictly associated with the ViewModel. So in this instance I'd be tempted just to get the form selected from the MVC model. I.e.

var calculateTotal = function() {

```
    var form = $('@String.Format("#{0}Content form", Model.FuelType)');
    if (!form.valid()) return;

    var formData = form.serialize();
```